# How to post figures on a new line in php?

Tags: php, newline, figure

I want to control when to put figures on a new line in php.   I can keep posting figures like so:

```
<A HREF="./images_local/figname.gif">
 <img height=196 width=128 src="./images_local/figname.gif"/></A>
<A HREF="./images_local/figname2.gif">
 <img height=196 width=128 src="./images_local/figname2.gif"/></A>
  <A HREF="./images_local/figname3.gif">
 <img height=196 width=128 src="./images_local/figname3.gif"/></A>
```

But they all post left to right, until they run out of space, at which point they begin a new line.  How do I control when to start posting those figures on a new line?

Thanks.

Comment: nothing to do with php, how about some html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a simple HTML issue and has nothing to do with php, but even if you code HTML in php you could just use the `<br>` tag for line break.

By the way, it is considered a good practice to keep all HTML tags (`<a>`) and attributes (`href=""`) in lower case. It just makes your code more readable and consistent with proper HTML markup recommendations. :)

Answer (score -1):

as mentioned above, the `<br>` works just fine, alternatively you can list your images with :

```
<ul><li><A HREF="./images_local/figname.gif"></li>
     <li><img height=196 width=128 src="./images_local/figname.gif"/></A>
    <A HREF="./images_local/figname2.gif">
     <img height=196 width=128 src="./images_local/figname2.gif"/></A>
      <A HREF="./images_local/figname3.gif">
     <img height=196 width=128 src="./images_local/figname3.gif"/></A></li>
</ul>
```

etc